# How to pull local XML configuration data into HTML file

Tags: html, xml, configuration-files

I'm working on a web project that fetches data (using Ruby) and then displays the data on a dashboard of widgets (designed in HTML/SCSS, linked via CoffeeScript).

I have a local configuration file that I would like to be accessible by both the Ruby scripts and the HTML. I managed to get the Ruby side of things working with `XmlConfigFile` but can't seem to find a similar solution for the HTML.

Everything I've found so far involves `xmlhttp.open("GET", <link>, false)`, which would be great if this weren't a local file.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "local file"? It sounds like you have a server-client model where the client is the dashboard and the server is the Ruby app… which has access to the config file, so I don't see why you can't get the config over HTTP.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry if anything is unclear, rather new to this kind of web dev. I'm using the Dashing.io framework to build this. I have a project folder containing sub-directories for HTML and Ruby jobs. In the parent directory, I have an XML file, and I'd simply like to be able to pull information from this file into the HTML code.

Comment: It is just a web server and a web page. You just need to write server side code (which, skimming the dashing.io homepage, looks like it should be expressed as a Job) to get the config data you care about.

Comment: @Quentin For example, I might have a widget titled `My Widget` that displays information from some URL `www.myurl.com`. I want to save `My Widget` and `www.myurl.com` in the XML configuration file and be able to access the URL from the Ruby and the widget name from the HTML.